# Вывод информации из многомерного массива php

Tags: php, массивы

Всем привет. Дан многомерный массив:

```
$result3 = [ 
// массив с авторами
"authors" => array( 
    "pasternak@gmail.com" => "Пастернак", 
    "joyce@gmail.com" => "Джойс", 
    "limonov@gmail.com" => "Лимонов", 
    "bukovski@gmail.com" => "Буковски"
    ),
//массив с книгами
"books" => array("Доктор Живаго", "Повелитель Мух", "Это я - Эдичка", "Женщины"), ];
```

Задача состоит в том, чтобы вывести на экран следующую информацию:

Книгу "Женщины" написал Буковски

Книгу "Доктор Живаго" написал Пастернак

и далее по аналогии. Подскажите пожалуйста как здесь правильно использовать foreach?

Comment: `foreach` перебирает массив по очереди. вы же приводите пример, где у вас сначала 3й элемент, потом нулевой. 
Задача просто вывести, или вывести в каком то необычном порядке?

Comment: Задача состоит чтобы вывести в формате:
“Книга <Название книги>, ее написал <Фио автора> (< email автора >)”, а затем перемешать книги и снова вывести информацию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я так понимаю что книги и писатели идут в одинаковом порядке. Поэтому можно сделать так:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($result3['authors'] as $email => $fio) {
    $book = $result3['books'][$i];
    echo $fio . ' => ' . $book;
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну, не идеально конечно, но как вариант:

```
$array = [
    'authors' => [
        'pasternak@gmail.com' => 'Пастернак',
        'joyce@gmail.com' => 'Джойс',
        'limonov@gmail.com' => 'Лимонов',
        'bukovski@gmail.com' => 'Буковски'
    ],
    'books' => [
        'Доктор Живаго', 'Повелитель Мух', 'Это я - Эдичка', 'Женщины'
    ]
];

foreach (array_values($array['authors']) as $key => $value)
{
    $k = array_keys($array['authors']);
    echo "Книга: {$array['books'][$key]}, ее написал: {$value}, email: {$k[$key]} \n";
}
```

Или такой вариант:

```
$data = [array_keys($array['authors']), array_values($array['authors']), $array['books']];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($data[0]); ++$i)
{
    echo "Книга: {$data[2][$i]}, ее написал: {$data[1][$i]}, email: {$data[0][$i]} \n";
}
```

Получаем нужный результат:

```
Книга: Доктор Живаго, ее написал: Пастернак, email: pasternak@gmail.com 
Книга: Повелитель Мух, ее написал: Джойс, email: joyce@gmail.com 
Книга: Это я - Эдичка, ее написал: Лимонов, email: limonov@gmail.com 
Книга: Женщины, ее написал: Буковски, email: bukovski@gmail.com
```